# Waswas and/or OCD

Tags: halal-haram, salat, allah, sin, waswasa

Please dont judge, but this is something I've been worried about for a while. I converted to Islam a few weeks ago and I started to try and be more religious lately but I feel like I might have some ocd, when I pray or do wudu, I get worried that I didnt do it right. And I feel like I make mistakes on accident that take me out of islam, and so I repent and I  repeat the shahadah a lot too, and still sometimes I'm worried that I'm not a muslim, and that I have to repeat my conversion process. For example, I performed ghusl today and prayed, but then I said something while talking to my friends that made me worried and feel like I may have accidentally made fun of a part of Islam, so I said    astaghfirullah and repeated the shahadah again. Is this normal, and am I still a Muslim?

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Aleikum Warahmatulahi Wabarakaatuhu

Relax and ignore the whisperings of Shaitan. We all forget how many Rakats (cycle) of prayers we performed. We sometimes forget that we are fasting and eat food or drink water.

Allah is very merciful and sees all that you do. Keep your intention (Niyah) pure in
your worship and you will be fine.

Learn as much as you can about the religion. It is not that easy to loose your Islam.
Spend sometime in Dhikr (Remembrance of Allah). If you can recite the Quran do so.
Take it easy and be the best Muslim you can be,

Answer (score 0):

The fact you show regret means you have a strong faith. Do your best to ignore and read Manzil which is a mixture of surahs. If you feel it getting worse it may be better to ask help from a scholar. May Allah help you and ease your current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Relax. You are absolutely a Muslim and you being worried and concerned is a good sign and it shows that you care. But that deosent mean that you should be so paranoid. Since you are new to islam Shaitan is trying to make it as hard for you as possible. Please ignore all this you're doing great.